# Стоит ли углубляться в Pascal, а также изучать Lazarus?

Tags: pascal, lazarus

3 месяца назад начал изучение Pascal. Проделывал разные упражнения, а также писал мелкие и бесполезные приложения. Уже хотел углубиться в Lazarus, появилось желание создавать программы с gui. Но блин, посмотришь на сайт с вакансиями везде требуется java, C#, PHP. Сейчас подумываю уйти в web, начать изучение PHP и javascript. К тому же база есть! Вот блин дилемма программисты помогите решить!

Comment: на правах PHPшника: если задумали бросаться в веб, то ни за что не беритесь за PHP, вместо яваскрипта лучше сразу dart смотреть, он вроде конвертируется в js без проблем. PHP и js - одни из самых идиотских языков на планете. Лучше руби или питон.

Comment: В городе работу php программисту легче найти. К тому же в pyhton не нравится разрозненность версий. Есть 2 и 3 ветка, а какую учить непонятно. Ведь они отличны друг от друга, но сам язык конечно вещь!

Comment: "На каждом заводе есть только один главный инженер, лучше я на обычного работягу пойду, ему работу легче найти".
Если вас устраивает получать среднее по городу - ок, но тогда непонятно, зачем идти в программисты, можно найти работу поприятней и посоциальней (если не интроверт). PHP программисту вообще легко найти работу, по той причине, что я описал выше - это язык совсем не высокого порядка, что по архитектуре, что по контингенту. Впрочем, еще легче валяться на диване, но вы почему-то отметаете эту возможность

Comment: Про третий питон просто забудьте. Все пользуются вторым, джанга, которая означает 50%+ времени питон-веб-разработчика, тоже висит на втором, третий вообще никого не интересует, потому что разработчики никак его не могут допилить, и, видимо не допилят никогда. А все ждут, когда это наконец случится. Если вы думаете, что в пыхе меньше геморроя - отнюдь, пока не делается реально большой проект (под который будет конфигурироваться сервак), нужно следить за тем, чтобы все модули были на месте, с версиями 5.х там та же чехарда (наконец-то переходят к ООП), только они выходят почаще.

Comment: >но сам язык конечно вещь!

Ненавижу его всей душой. Возможностей больше, поведение более предсказуемое, но некоторые моменты просто выносят мозг, я уж молчу про то, что чертов self из методов за столько лет никто так и не убрал.

Comment: @Fike 

    Ненавижу его всей душой. 

Опасно это для здоровья. Аккуратнее надо. Тем более, что-что, но ООП там есть (видимо я так никогда и не пойму любви к ООП, Фатх и другим террористическим организациям). А Ваши рассуждения на тему php/ЗелёныйЗмей мне чем-то напомнили десятое правило Гринспена.

Comment: Зря заминусовали вопрос. Может и не по теме, может и холиварный, но мне ответы на него помогли. Вот когда C# будет компилировать в монолит, который невозможно легко декомпилировать и который не будет требовать установки многотонного .NET Framework, то я с удовольствием переведу свои Delphi-проекты на него.

Answer (score 5):

Pascal больше для обучения подходит, а этот Lazarus просто как игрушка, я не думаю что на нем кто-то когда либо писал "очень большое и крутое". И задерживаться на нем я бы не советовал, просто времени очень много потеряешь. Определись уже точно в какой области хочешь оперировать ну и выбирай из реальных и востребованных ЯП - Java / C# / PHP

Answer (score 2):

Есть смысл сосредоточится на изучении алгоритмов, и подходов к решению классических проблем. Языки программирования меняются. Главное выработать правильное мышление.

Что касается языков, лично мое мнение: Java. На примере Java можно прекрасно прочувствовать концепцию ООП. И начав изучать Java, у вас есть несколько путей развития: WEB или Android.
Да и GUI на ней легко можно делать.

> углубиться в Lazarus

Звучит немного странно :) Это как углубиться в калькулятор вместо углубления в математику. Lazarus - всего лишь среда разработки.

Comment: Ну имею в виду углубиться в разработку приложений в среде Lazarus! Ну, извиняйте за курьез)

Answer (score 1):

Сорри за некропостинг, но я всё-же отвечу.

> а этот Lazarus просто как игрушка, я не думаю что на нем кто-то когда либо писал "очень большое и крутое"

Гуглить надо перед тем, как что-нибудь подумать ;-)

С использованием Lazarus написано довольно много проектов, в том числе "больших и крутых" и довольно известных: 64-битная версия Total Commander, Ubuntu Control Center, XERO CODER (коммерческая кроссплатформенная IDE), графический редактор LazPaint (альтернатива paint.net), MyNotex, игрульки всякие и даже игровые движки и конструкторы(ToastEngine, Game Maker) и ещё много всяких больших и не очень программ.

Со списком ознакомиться можно тут:
http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Application_Gallery
http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Projects_using_Lazarus

На Pascal умудрились даже ОС'и написать:
http://wiki.freepascal.org/Operating_Systems_written_in_FPC

Так что Pascal/Lazarus - совсем не игрушка, а серьёзный инструмент в умелых руках. Только один недостаток есть - его непопулярность. Сейчас .NET и Java - мейнстрим. Поэтому надо подстраиваться и осваивать всякие C# и другие зачем-то созданные малоинтересные вещи.

Comment: А так же разбираться в том, что нагуглили, у Lazarus есть такие свойства как:

> Поддерживает преобразование проектов Delphi
> Поддержка множества типов синтаксиса Pascal: Object Pascal, Turbo Pascal, Free Pascal, etc
> Поддерживаемые для компиляции ОС: Linux, Microsoft Windows (Win32, Win64), Mac OS X, etc

Мало чего из перечисленного в Lazarus как таковое именно писалось, там только собиралось. Брали готовый проект из delphi или еще откуда и переносили в Lazarus, после чего собирали. Все только ради того, чтобы перекомпилировать проекты под отличные от обычного Windows 32 платформы.

Comment: А по поводу Pascal и Lazarus, почему бы не воспользоваться современными решениями: компонентный паскаль и BlackBox Component Builder? На Блэкбоксе создано ПО для расчета бортовых фазированных решеток истребителя Eurofighter (полный объём ПО — около миллиона строк). На Блэкбоксе сделана система управления крупнейшего каскада ГЭС на Амазонке (корпорация Alstom Power), ряд приложений в  экспериментальной и теоретической ядерной физики. На BlackBox разработана промышленная ОС реального времени — JBed, которая позволяет выполнять модули Component Pascal и классы Java.

Comment: @Alex Krass, а вот данные по Open Source проектам показывают

[совсем другую картину](http://www.ohloh.net/languages/compare?measure=projects&percent=true&l0=c&l1=csharp&l2=pascal&l3=cpp&l5=-1&commit=Update).

Не интересен Pascal (со всеми его производными), ну совсе не популярен.

Comment: @avp, это как и язык [Lisp](http://www.ohloh.net/languages/compare?measure=projects&percent=true&l0=c&l1=csharp&l2=cpp&l3=lisp&l4=pascal&l6=-1&commit=Update). Область применения Pascal-подобных языков  довольно специфическая - сверхнадежные системы с максимальным исключением ошибок человеческого фактора: военная промышленность, медицинское оборудование, банковские системы, мобильная связь и другое. Пытаться искать Open Source, все равно, что искать вакансию программиста логики боеголовок. То, что Вы их не находите, не значит, что они не существует. Но так да - широкому рынку это не интересно.

Comment: Да, Pascal, Lisp, Haskell, Ada, Fortran ... -- величины одного порядка. 

Впрочем, значительно опережают, скажем, Prolog.