# Компонентный паскаль, ищу мануалы

Tags: документация, oberon

Всем привет

Для начала подношу две пиалы чая @Alex Krass за комментарий [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/285671)

> почему бы не воспользоваться современными решениями: компонентный паскаль и BlackBox Component Builder?

Скачал я эту штуку, порадовался, что кому-то это еще надо, влюбился в местное "не равно" (`#`) и ретрофутуристичные капсовые операторы и даже сделал консольный экзешник, выдающий главную страницу хэшкода в `StdOut`.

Одно "НО": переломал себе руки-ноги, пока искал нужные компоненты, создавал Commander'ы и пытался заставить `WinNet.connect` съесть структуру `sockaddr_in`.

В связи с чем вопрос, есть ли вменяемый мануал по языку / компонентам?

Можно даже на бумаге. Основные тексты (вроде "Сообщения о языке" и встроенной справки, а также форум OberonCore) использую, но практических моментов вроде сборки-компиляции под разные оси и *полезных* примеров в них чуть более, чем нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, вот с документацией и литературой конечно сложности. Источников не много, в подавляющем большинстве иностранные. Так же стоит отметить, что компонентный паскаль это тот же Оберон-2 с уточнениями, поэтому присутствует только "Сообщения о языке" и много об Обероне. Вот что есть:

[БГПУ Физфак: об обероне](http://www.physics.uni-altai.ru/community/wiki/Oberon)

[Тот же OberonCore](http://oberoncore.ru/library/start)

[Документация и ссылки zinnamturm](http://www.zinnamturm.eu/links.htm)

К сожалению история, но можно выйти на следы в гугле по названиям

Так же можно почитать:

1. J. Stanley Warford. Programming with BlackBox
2. Brett S.Hallett. Developing Programs with BlackBox Oberon

Comment: Вооо огромная благодарность и третья пиала чая) 

Кажется, тут ссылок на пару месяцев. И исходники, что даже важнее. Отлично) 

*ЗЫ: только последняя ссылка побитая*

Comment: Последняя, в общем-то ссылка на нее есть и в третьей: http://web.archive.org/web/20120307082235/http://www.cetus-links.org/oo_oberon.html